# ubuntu wont boot, black screen on start up

Tags: boot

I have an Asus G73jh laptop that I am attempting to reinstall ubuntu on. I previously had windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 loaded on it. I attempted to update ubuntu 12.04 earlier today which came up with an error during the update. I decided to try and reinstall ubuntu on the partion that already had it with 14.04 from a usb. Upon doing so, I accidentally erased  windows 7 by picking the option that said replace Ubuntu 12.04 (I figured it would leave my other partition alone, I was wrong). So I lost my windows 7 partition and then Ubuntu would not load. I got a blank black screen upon boot. I figured something happened to the grub so I decided to try a complete reinstall and erase the whole disk. However, I am still getting a blank black screen upon boot. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: If I choose "something else" when installing ubuntu, it pulls this up. 

/dev/sda
free space 1mb
/dev/sda1 efi 536mb 33used
/dev/sda2 ext4 493195mb 12035mb used
/dev/sda3 swap 6373mb
free space 1mb

Comment: So I managed to fix this issue after some research so I figured I would post what I did for anyone else to refer to.

I booted back into my Ubuntu usb installer and installed boot repair through the terminal. I found the instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and followed the instructions listed. I hope this helps anyone else that ran into this issue.

Comment: How about writing the solution as an answer and then marking it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix this issue after some research so I figured I would post what I did for anyone else to refer to. I booted back into my Ubuntu usb installer and installed boot repair through the terminal. I found the instructions here help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and followed the instructions listed. I hope this helps anyone else that ran into this issue.